# Display posts on tag.php template?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Is it possible to create a `tag.php` template that when you navigate to the url `www.domain.com/tag/architecture/` it will display all the custom posts that have been tagged with that specific tag? And so on for various other tags?

What code will I need to include on my template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes You can create,below is the code i used to display custom post type "knowledge"

```
<?php
global $query_string;
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&post_type=knowledge');
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

This will help you understand hierarchy of templates:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Use of $query_string (example) available here:

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Comment: Thanks. I understand the hierarchy of the templates it was just the loop I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png), you can create a file called `tag.php` which will be used instead of `index.php` if a tag page is displayed. You can also prepare separate templates for specific tags.

The best way is to start by creating a copy of your theme's `index.php` and calling it `tag.php`, this way you'll have some basic code working. Then you can modify `tag.php` to fit your needs - probably by editing [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), or maybe changing some includes if your theme loads the loop from separate file. (but in this case you should consider editing `index.php` to load some other loop for tag pages - `is_tag()` may come in handy)